# MySQL 5.7 isn't using new innodb buffer pool settings

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-5.7, buffer-pool

I have a very tiny VM which keeps running out of memory. I believe this is due to the buffer pool size. Default appears to be 128M for `innodb_buffer_pool_size` and `innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size`. So I've decided to reduce it to 64MB to see if I can stop the problem. However, my updates in the .cnf files aren't being respected when restarting mysql.

Every time I run the following command, I still get the 128MB value:

```
SELECT @@innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size
```

I've also checked that `innodb_buffer_pool_instances` is 1

Here are my confs:

**/etc/mysql/my.cnf (unchanged from install):**

```
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/
```

**/etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf:**

```
[mysql]
innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size=67108864
innodb_buffer_pool_size=67108864
```

**/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysql.cnf (unchanged from install):**

```
#
# The MySQL database server configuration file.
#
# You can copy this to one of:
# - "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" to set global options,
# - "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
#
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

# This will be passed to all mysql clients
# It has been reported that passwords should be enclosed with ticks/quotes
# escpecially if they contain "#" chars...
# Remember to edit /etc/mysql/debian.cnf when changing the socket location.

# Here is entries for some specific programs
# The following values assume you have at least 32M ram

[mysqld_safe]
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice        = 0

[mysqld]
#
# * Basic Settings
#
user        = mysql
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306
basedir     = /usr
datadir     = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir      = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking
#
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
bind-address        = 127.0.0.1
#
# * Fine Tuning
#
key_buffer_size     = 16M
max_allowed_packet  = 16M
thread_stack        = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8
# This replaces the startup script and checks MyISAM tables if needed
# the first time they are touched
myisam-recover-options  = BACKUP
#max_connections        = 100
#table_open_cache       = 64
#thread_concurrency     = 10
#
# * Query Cache Configuration
#
query_cache_limit   = 1M
query_cache_size        = 16M
#
# * Logging and Replication
#
# Both location gets rotated by the cronjob.
# Be aware that this log type is a performance killer.
# As of 5.1 you can enable the log at runtime!
#general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
#general_log             = 1
#
# Error log - should be very few entries.
#
log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
#
# Here you can see queries with especially long duration
#slow_query_log     = 1
#slow_query_log_file    = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
#long_query_time = 2
#log-queries-not-using-indexes
#
# The following can be used as easy to replay backup logs or for replication.
# note: if you are setting up a replication slave, see README.Debian about
#       other settings you may need to change.
#server-id      = 1
#log_bin            = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
expire_logs_days    = 10
max_binlog_size   = 100M
#binlog_do_db       = include_database_name
#binlog_ignore_db   = include_database_name
#
# * InnoDB
#
# InnoDB is enabled by default with a 10MB datafile in /var/lib/mysql/.
# Read the manual for more InnoDB related options. There are many!
#
# * Security Features
#
# Read the manual, too, if you want chroot!
# chroot = /var/lib/mysql/
#
# For generating SSL certificates I recommend the OpenSSL GUI "tinyca".
#
# ssl-ca=/etc/mysql/cacert.pem
# ssl-cert=/etc/mysql/server-cert.pem
# ssl-key=/etc/mysql/server-key.pem
```

Log files don't show any errors either:

```
2019-08-08T08:13:12.180236Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2019-08-08T08:13:12.182811Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.7.27-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) starting as process 6041 ...
2019-08-08T08:13:12.188241Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
2019-08-08T08:13:12.188394Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2019-08-08T08:13:12.188452Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2019-08-08T08:13:12.188502Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2019-08-08T08:13:12.188550Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2019-08-08T08:13:12.188602Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2019-08-08T08:13:12.188957Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2019-08-08T08:13:12.189160Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2019-08-08T08:13:12.193452Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2019-08-08T08:13:12.204172Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2019-08-08T08:13:12.207458Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
2019-08-08T08:13:12.219975Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2019-08-08T08:13:12.235065Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2019-08-08T08:13:12.235313Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2019-08-08T08:13:12.563990Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2019-08-08T08:13:12.565155Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2019-08-08T08:13:12.565279Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2019-08-08T08:13:12.565693Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2019-08-08T08:13:12.616072Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.27 started; log sequence number 14916453
2019-08-08T08:13:12.616771Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2019-08-08T08:13:12.622407Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2019-08-08T08:13:12.624060Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 190808  8:13:12
2019-08-08T08:13:12.625615Z 0 [Warning] Failed to set up SSL because of the following SSL library error: SSL context is not usable without certificate and private key
2019-08-08T08:13:12.625733Z 0 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '127.0.0.1'; port: 3306
2019-08-08T08:13:12.625794Z 0 [Note]   - '127.0.0.1' resolves to '127.0.0.1';
2019-08-08T08:13:12.625903Z 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.0.0.1'.
2019-08-08T08:13:12.637485Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2019-08-08T08:13:12.637833Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.7.27-0ubuntu0.18.04.1'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  (Ubuntu)
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: It looks like you edited the WRONG include file.  There is an area for INNODB in the longer named file (near the end).  Put your 2 lines there and they WILL be a part of the [mysqld] section and likely honored on next stop/start cycle.  Whatever lines you added in the first file should be removed to get back to 'released' content.  Disclaimer: I am the content author of website named in my profile, Network profile, contact for assistance.  Will be out of my office this afteroon.

Comment: Have you made any progress on getting your config changes implemented?